# How to convert seconds that be match with All Calendars?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, countdown

I'm Using `moment.js` and I Want to Convert Secends to:

- years
- months
- days
- hours
- minutes
- seconds

**Code:**

```
var tz = moment.tz.guess(),              
    date = moment.tz("2017-11-03 12:00", "America/New_York"),  //    moment.parseZone("2017-11-03T00:00:00.000+03:30")
    now = new Date(),                                          //    2017-11-02T01:54:05.235Z
    diff = (date.valueOf() / 1000) - (now.getTime() / 1000)
    console.log(diff)      //31463.726999998093
```

But Days in Month is different in Hijri and Gregorian Calendar, How Should I Convert Time Interval with Standard way?

[Info Link](https://www.islamicfinder.org/islamic-calendar/)

**New Update:**

I Don't Like to use 124 min, Because we Have 1-59 Min, after That We Have 1 Hour, And In each Calender we Haven't any Specified month Because the month is 28, 29 or ... Days, and we have Leap year too.

**English Calendar 2017**

```
January is      31 Days
February is    28  Days   
March is          31 Days
April is            30 Days
May is              31 Days
June is              30 Days
July is               31 Days
Auguest is       31 Days
September is  30 Days
October is      31 Days
November is 30 Days
December is  31 Days
```

**Persian Calendar 1396**

```
Farvardin is     31 Days
Ordibehesht is 31 Days
Khordad is        31 Days
Tir is                   31 Days
Mordad is         31 Days
Shahrivar is     31 Days
Mehr is              30 Days
Aban is              30 Days
Azar is               30 Days
Dey is                 30 Days
Bahman is        30 Days
Esfand is           29 Days
```

**Example:**

Start = `1 Feb` and End = `2 March` 
We Have 1 Month and 2 Days in English Calendar, But in **other Calendars** How Should we use an Layout? Month is 30,29 or 31?
Please Look at this photo:
[image: Photo]

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Do you want the difference to be 2 hours and 4 minutes or 2 hours and 124 minutes when the dates differ 124 minutes. 2. You cannot show month and year difference only based on milliseconds, months and years have different lengths. The minimum you need is start date. So would you like a function that takes 2 dates or 1 date and ms difference?

Comment: I Updated My Question.

Comment: So I assume a function that takes 2 dates and returns their difference based on `Intl.DateTimeFormat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat I cannot find support in native JS for Hijri and momentjs plugins do not seem to be maintained (found some but no recent maintenance and too many open issues)

Comment: I'm New in Programming, and I Don't know What should I do!.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/

Comment: Is there any plugin to work with all languages? Like auto guess ()